# how to register azure mobile service .net backend custom api

Tags: java, android, azure, mobile, azure-mobile-services

I have created a .NET backend Mobile Service on Windows Azure using the code sample provided on the website [article](http://azure.microsoft.com/tr-tr/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-get-started-custom-authentication/).
Now I am trying to register a user with android client but I can't.

My backend registration control looks like below;

```
 [AuthorizeLevel(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)]
public class CustomRegistrationController : ApiController
{
    public ApiServices Services { get; set; }

    // POST api/CustomRegistration
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(RegistrationRequest registrationRequest)
    {
        if (!Regex.IsMatch(registrationRequest.username, "^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,}$"))
        {
            return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid username (at least 4 chars, alphanumeric only)");
        }
        else if (registrationRequest.password.Length < 8)
        {
            return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid password (at least 8 chars required)");
        }

        hadContext context = new hadContext();
        Account account = context.Accounts.Where(a => a.Username == registrationRequest.username).SingleOrDefault();
        if (account != null)
        {
            return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Username already exists");
        }
        else
        {
            byte[] salt = CustomLoginProviderUtils.generateSalt();
            Account newAccount = new Account
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                Username = registrationRequest.username,
                Salt = salt,
                SaltedAndHashedPassword = CustomLoginProviderUtils.hash(registrationRequest.password, salt)
            };
            context.Accounts.Add(newAccount);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        }
    }

}
```

I wrote this code on android client app

```
   public void register(View view) {

       if (   txtUsername.getText().toString().equals("")
           && txtPassword.getText().toString().equals(""))
       {
           Log.w(TAG,"tüm alanları girmen gerek");
           return;
       }
    else
       {
           RegistrationRequest register = new RegistrationRequest();
           register.setUsername(txtUsername.getText().toString());
           register.setPassword(txtUsername.getText().toString());
           mClient.invokeApi("CustomRegistration",register,RegistrationRequest.class,
                   new ApiOperationCallback<RegistrationRequest>() {
                       @Override
                       public void onCompleted(RegistrationRequest result, Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
                          if (exception==null)
                          {
                              Log.w(TAG,"kayıt başarılı");
                          }
                           else
                          {
                              Log.w(TAG,"kayıt başarısız " +exception);
                          }
                       }
                   });
       }

}
```

It's not working. How should I do for registration.

Comment: What is not working? Do you get an error? If so, what kind, and is there more information in the response? Also, please do not attach images for the code, paste the code instead.

Comment: when I call the invokeApi it's return exception. The given exception about the password mobile service wants at least 8 chars long from client but evet I enter 8 chars it's return exception